# Is "I achieved better efficiency ..." proper grammar?

Tags: grammar

Some woman told me that it was not.

If something was "efficient", you could not make it better. You could however say, "Greater efficiency".

Is this true?

Comment: Whether you can improve efficiency to make it better is debatable. But *greater efficiency* is certainly the usual expression.

Comment: To some extent that woman is correct -- we measure *degree* of efficiency rather than *quality* of efficiency.  However in normal conversation this is a blurry line and we often say *better* when we should say *greater*.

Comment: @Andrew I agree.  I hear "better efficiency" almost daily from the native AmE scientists and engineers I work with.

Comment: There's even greater efficiencies in some tech contexts. Also, improved efficiency.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hear the phrase "better efficiency" regularly.  It's common in colloquial English, but it isn't grammatical.

**Better**  is used to describe an improvement in quality.  "I received a better grade [on my homework]" or "I enjoy a better living than my parents had."

**Greater**  is used to describe a measurable (and often unspecified) growth.  "He lept to a greater height" or "It flew with greater velocity."

Therefore...

> I achieved greater efficiency...

A third choice, which works both ways, is:

**Improved**  is used to indicate a positive or beneficial change of any kind.  "We improved the plane's velocity" or "We saw improved voter turnout."

However, unlike "better" and "greataer," "improve" is can be either a verb or an adjective.  Therefore, you might hear...

> I achieved improved efficiency...

But you would also hear (and perhaps more frequently):

> I improved the efficiency...